# What is the purpose of this string argument in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

In the following function, there is the line:

```
var username=getCookie("username");
```

Here's the whole function:

```
function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
```

What is the point of the "username" argument being passed above?

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

The [whole code is here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't just a parameter? Get the cookie whose name is "username".

Comment: Well, yes - but we are supposed to enter anything we like(not "username") like we can enter "bob" e.g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.cookie` contains all the cookies relating to this page/session in the format:

```
"<cookie_name_1>=<cookie_value_1>; <cookie_name_2>=<cookie_value_2>; ..."
```

When you pass `"username"` for the c_name argument of the `getCookie()` function, you are telling it that that's the `<cookie_name>` you're interested in.

That function basically goes through `document.cookie` putting `<cookie_name>` in `x` and `<cookie_value>` in `y` each time it iterates. If the current `<cookie_name>` equals `"username"` (in your example), then it will return the `<cookie_value>`

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are stored in a name/value pair format, per-site, sort of like a querystring looks.

So when you're accessing the cookie, you can't just say `document.cookie.username` and get the value, you actually have to split on the delimiters.

In the getCookie() code (which is very inefficient, btw), it will search for the name, and then get the value, which is separated by an `=`.

Answer (score 1):

That is the **name** of the cookie, you can store more than one cookie at the time and the name is important to get the cookie you want.